# My svg rectangle movement

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to move to a rectangle. When it reaches the end of the line, make a line break and put it at the beginning of the next line. The rectangle does not take well coordinates to make the line break. Any ideas? This is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    var rect = document.getElementById('player');
    var x = rect.getAttribute('x')*1,
        y = rect.getAttribute('y')*1;
    setInterval(move, 30);

    function move()
    {
        if (rect.getAttribute('x') < 500){
            rect.x.baseVal.value = ++x;
        }
        else if (rect.getAttribute('x') >= 500){
            rect.x.baseVal.value = x-250;
            rect.y.baseVal.value = y+250;
        }
    }
    ]]></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [svg rectangle movement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285785/svg-rectangle-movement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the value from the element is unnecessarily expensive and in your case it seems that it is getting or setting the value too late. Instead of getting the value on each loop keep track of a for `x` and `y`:

```
var rect = document.getElementById('player');
var x = rect.getAttribute('x')*1,
    y = rect.getAttribute('y')*1;
var pos_x = 0, pos_y = 0;
setInterval(move, 30); 

function move(i)
{
    pos_x++;
    if (pos_x < 500){
        rect.setAttribute('x', pos_x);
    }
    else {
        pos_y +=10
        pos_x = 0;
        rect.setAttribute('x', pos_y);
        rect.setAttribute('y', pos_y);
    }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMwMb/